# Install create-react-app in a subdomain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm doing a project in React using the [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) command. I have my server with NodeJS and I want to install the project in the main domain like www.mydomain.com (I know how to do it). But I also want to install a test version in test.mydomain.com. It is possible to install it in the subdomain and how could I do it?

Comment: Do you know how to setup a sub domain with your web server? If you do you should be able to create a new react project in a test folder and maybe change the <base href="test"> and see if that works

Comment: it is depending on your hosting environment for me personally i have digital ocean account and easily managed to do that by using nginx and pm2